# jquery plugin: integrate papaparse csv to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, csv

I have search for jquery csv to json converter and I found this plugin (http://papaparse.com/)
but I dont know how to implement it properly. I copied the example's code and modified it but seems not working.

this is the modified code:

```
$(function()
{
    var finished = 0, queued = 0;
    var start, end;
    $('#submit').live('click',(function()
        {
            var self = $(this);
            self.prop('disabled', true);

            queued = $('#file')[0].files.length;
            $('#file').parse(
            {
                complete: function(data, file, inputElem, event)
                {
                    finished++;
                    $('#output').empty();
                    render(data);
                    if (finished == queued)
                        done(file.name);
                },
            });
        }));

    function done(filename)
    {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
        finished = 0;
        queued = 0;
        status("");
    }
    function output(str)
    {
        $('#output').text(str);
    }
    function render(results)
    {
        output(JSON.stringify(results, undefined, 2));
    }
});
```

this is my html code:

```
<input type="file" name="serial_2" value="" id="file" />
<span id="submit">test</span>
<code id="output"></code>
```

anybody can help me?